# Poder manipular las urls de las páginas

Tags: wordpress

Tengo una web con la url `www.miblog.com` Al crearle una página la url sería `www.miblog.com/pagina`

> ¿Existe alguna manera de que yo le agregue más elementos "dentro" de
>   esa página?

Así como se ven en las categorías.
Ejemplo: que cree otra página y la url se vea: `www.miblog.com/pagina/pagina2`
Y le cree otra página más y se vea: `www.miblog.com/pagina/pagina2/pagina3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al crear una página en wordpress en los "Atributos de página" puedes seleccionar Una pagina superior, cuando haces eso, la url de la pagina sera www.miblog.com/pagina-superior/pagina-creada.

Para que se vea el nombre de la página y no caracteres raros tienes que modificar los permalinks en "Opciones / Enlaces permanentes" y seleccionar "Nombre de la entrada"

https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks